# typo3 rte softhyphens (&shy;) are being ignored

Tags: typo3, rte

I tried to use softhyphens in my TYPO3 6.0.6 installation, but they are ignored. I use a ts-config RTE file my configuration is:

```
showButtons := addToList(insertsofthyphen)
parseFunc_RTE.allowTags = shy
RTE.default.proc.allowTags (shy)
```

But nothing works. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I think you can leave out the `allowTags` stuff, as this is not a tag, but an entity. Can you be more precise with "nothing works"? Is the entity visible in RTE after a click on the button? Does it appear in the HTML mode in the RTE? Does it get saved in the DB? Does it appear in the HTML in frontend?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with TYPO 4.7 the ONLY thing that is needed to activate soft hyphens in RTE and frontend is activating the respective RTE button through this TS Config line:

```
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(insertsofthyphen);
```

There is no need to add `shy` to any config sections (`allowTags`, `externalBlocks` or whatsoever) as `insertsofthyphen` does NOT insert a `&shy;` HTML entity, but a character with code 173 (hex AD). This character is an older notion for a soft hyphen than the shy entity and there are reports that it is more browser compatible.

This special character is invisible by definition and remains invisible in the RTE and in the frontend – even in HTML code view! This might give the impression that the soft hyphen button is not working. But there is a simple way to detect its output:
In RTE step over the characters of a word with the cursor keys. At the position of a soft hyphen you will have to press the cursor key **twice** until the cursor actually moves. The soft hyphen "consumes" one keystroke without a visible change in cursor position.

Comment: Just used for a TYPO3 6.2 installation. Workes very well.

Comment: Works for TYPO3 7.6

Answer (score 2):

I tested a lot and realised, that the RTE does in fact not ignore softhyphens. They are just invisible in the BE, but not in the FE. I placed a softhyphen entity via the special chars button. After placing it, i couldn't see, where i put it. There is no visible code that says "& shy;". But you can see, that it works in the FE. Thats fine by me. It would be better, to see the entity... I think we are stuck with it, unless somebody releases a "bugfix"(not really a bug).

Comment: I tried to put the softhyphens in the rte again and I found out, that it really works, but ownly when you put in the softhyphens two times. The softhyphens is not shown in the rte Editor after saving for the first time. After saving the second time the softhyphens is really saved. Thank you Jozze for the hint, that the softhyphens works in the frontend. I checked that and you are right.

Answer (score -1):

As stated by Michael you don't need the allowTags lines.

What do you mean with "they are ignored"? Is the button displayed? Please beware that you won't see the soft hyphens, neither in the source code nor in the RTE directly.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The insert soft hyphen button doesn't insert the HTML entity (&shy;) to the source code, it inserts the soft hyphen sign (Alt+0173). So it won't be visible as a symbol neither in the RTE nor in the source code view nor in the database as long as there is no need to break a word. Stanislas Rolland, developer of the RTE, stated the same: "The soft hyphen is not affected by any RTE configuration setting and is not processed in any way by the RTE after its insertion."

Comment: I ment with ignored, that I have to save my rte two times, that the softhyphen is saved correctly. I wasn´t aware, that the softhyphens aren´t visible in the RTE, which is difficult for contentediting.